# The maximum size of the picture - background-image

Tags: css, background-image, max

I want to put on a web page background. I have a background of large 1600px x 1200px. This is a jpg picture. The image size is 320 kilobytes Can I put this big picture in the background? The site will be delayed? As the big picture should be up in the background?

I want to make a quick website. I can not cut image. I give it all, you can not use CSS to repeat

Comment: You can, and it will be delayed. But JPG has a progressive scan mode, so it will show up as pixely, then scan over. This can help the load time of the website a great deal. Try saving it in progressive scan mode, with as many passes as you can set. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a great tutorial for full page backgrounds

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

You can always increase compression (by reducing quality) of that `.jpg` file to greatly reduce its size.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Effects_of_JPEG_compression